# Atomic "check signal and enter system call" operation

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix

I'm trying to implement my own cancellation-point mechanism in C++. The code is mainly targeted at Linux but I hope it to be portable among POSIX systems.

For obvious reason, every blocking system call must be a cancellation point, otherwise the thread may block forever and nothing will be able to wake it up. Currently I use signal to achieve that. When a thread receives a special signal representing a cancellation request, the signal handler sets up a thread-local flag. If that thread is blocked on some system call it will fail with `errno == EINTR`. Then it will have chance to check the flag.

But soon I found the above method isn't perfect. If the signal comes first, and then the thread enters the blocking system call, it gets into forever blocking as well. Checking the flag before each blocking call doesn't make things good enough. The signal may come just after the check:

```
if(cancelled)
    throw CancellationException();
 // <--- The signal comes here. ---> //
blocking_call();
```

Here's my problem: Is there a way to make sure when I enter a system call, the cancellation flag is not set? If not, what is the common practice to design such cancellation points?

Comment: Have you checked how other systems do it, like [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I had a brief check at boost threads. According to its documentation, it has only a few predefined interruption points. If a boost thread is blocked on a syscall, it will not be interrupted.

Comment: How are you signalling your threads?  Vanilla POSIX signals are delivered arbitrarily to one of the threads; if you're directing toward a particular thread, are you using `pthread_kill`?

Comment: @sheu: Yes, I am using `pthread_kill`. And I wish a single-threaded process could be cancelled in the same way by another process using `kill`.

Comment: @hpsMouse: at the risk of sounding stupid, err, if you're fine with `pthreads`, why don't you just use their cancellations then?

Comment: @sheu: I have to throw an exception so RAII classes can clean their resources.

Comment: @sheu: A good idea anyway. Maybe I should have a look at pthreads in gnu libc and see how they did it.

Comment: Can you please specify the blocking call ? Is it something with sockets ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it an actual answer.

If you're looking to do stuff on cancellation for pthreads, take a look at [pthread cancellation handlers](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html).  Might it work to throw your exceptions from there?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to throw exceptions inside pthread cancellation handlers. You can't even `longjmp` out of it.